# redirecting by loginstatus from local.storage

Tags: reactjs, session, react-router, session-state

im trying to implement session management and private routes into my application and for some reason the solution im using now is bugging in a way. my log in updates login status to true if logged in,and stores it in localstorage as storedLoginStatus then im trying to check this value when refreshing the page so it keeps me on the same page i was even after refresh or language change which refreshes the page but every refresh sends me to the not logged in screen.

anyone know how i can fix this?

here is PrivateRoutes.js which handles redirecting upon loginstatus:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavbarContext } from "../../NavbarContext";

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { loginStatus, setLoginStatus } = useContext(NavbarContext);
   const storedLoginStatus = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loginStatus"));
   let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const storedLoginStatus = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loginStatus"));
    if (storedLoginStatus !== null) {
      setLoginStatus(storedLoginStatus);
      console.log("stored = " + storedLoginStatus);
    }
  }, [setLoginStatus]);

  return storedLoginStatus ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/*" />;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

this is navbar context which handles the loginstatus and sets it (it also handles project seletion, not relevant to this question):

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NavbarData from "./components/Navbar/NavbarData";

export const NavbarContext = createContext();

export const NavbarProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);
  const [navbarData, setNavbarData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedProjectIndex, setSelectedProjectIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedProjectIndex = localStorage.getItem("selectedProjectIndex");
    const storedLoginStatus = localStorage.getItem("loginStatus");

    if (storedProjectIndex !== null) {
      const parsedIndex = parseInt(storedProjectIndex, 10);
      if (
        !isNaN(parsedIndex) &&
        parsedIndex >= 0 &&
        parsedIndex < NavbarData.length
      ) {
        setSelectedProjectIndex(parsedIndex);
      }
    }

    if (storedLoginStatus !== null) {
      setLoginStatus(JSON.parse(storedLoginStatus));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(
      "selectedProjectIndex",
      selectedProjectIndex.toString()
    );
    localStorage.setItem("loginStatus", JSON.stringify(loginStatus));

    setNavbarData(NavbarData[selectedProjectIndex]?.tabs || []);
  }, [selectedProjectIndex, loginStatus]);

  return (
    <NavbarContext.Provider
      value={{
        navbarData,
        selectedProjectIndex,
        setSelectedProjectIndex,
        setLoginStatus,
        loginStatus,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </NavbarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

index.js handles routing:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./i18n";

import React from "react";

import MonitoringOverview from "./routes/MonitoringOverview";
import PerformanceQuality from "./routes/PerformanceQuality";
import Finance from "./routes/Finance";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import LoginScreen from "./routes/LoginScreen/LoginScreen";
import UserConfig from "./routes/UserConfig/UserConfig.js";
import Simulation from "./routes/Simulation";
import Fraud from "./routes/Fraud";
import Deployment from "./routes/Deployment";
import Planning from "./routes/Planning";
import Settings from "./routes/Settings";

import PrivateRoutes from "./routes/Utils/PrivateRoutes";
import NotLogged from "./routes/Utils/NotLoggedIn";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <NavbarProvider>
        <LoginScreen />
      </NavbarProvider>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/*",
    element: (
      <NavbarProvider>
        <NotLogged />
      </NavbarProvider>
    ),
  },

  {
    element: (
      <>
        <NavbarProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <PrivateRoutes />
        </NavbarProvider>
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "monitoringoverview",
        element: <MonitoringOverview />,
      },

      {
        path: "performancequality",
        element: <PerformanceQuality />,
      },

      {
        path: "finance",
        element: <Finance />,
      },
      {
        path: "simulation",
        element: <Simulation />,
      },
      {
        path: "userconfig",
        element: <UserConfig />,
      },
      {
        path: "fraud",
        element: <Fraud />,
      },
      {
        path: "deployment",
        element: <Deployment />,
      },
      {
        path: "planning",
        element: <Planning />,
      },
      {
        path: "settings",
        element: <Settings />,
      },

      // 
      {
        path: "cashflowoverview",
        element: <CashflowOverview />,
      },

      //Elections
      {
        path: "elections",
        element: <Elections />,
      },
      {
        path: "whatif",
        element: <Whatif />,
      },

      //
      {
        path: "overview",
        element: <Overview />,
      },
      {
        path: "resourcemanagement",
        element: <ResourceManagement />,
      },

      //SuperGaz
      {
        path: "energymonitoring",
        element: <EnergyMonitoring />,
      },

      //
      {
        path: "monitoring",
        element: <Monitoring />,
      },
      {
        path: "inquiry",
        element: <Inquiry />,
      },

      //

     
    ],
  },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

and this is the login screen with its logic:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "./LoginScreen.css";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarContext } from "../../NavbarContext";

// i18n implementation
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import i18next from "i18next";

function LoginScreen() {
  //Context Provider

  // React States

  const [errorMessages, setErrorMessages] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const { setLoginStatus } = useContext(NavbarContext);

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const lngs = {
    en: { nativeName: "English" },
    fr: { nativeName: "French" },
  };

  const lng = i18next.language;

  const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);

    window.location.reload();
  };

  //Database for demo authentication
  const database = [
    {
      username: "11111",
      password: "1111111",
    },
    {
      username: "1111",
      password: "1111111",
    },
  ];

  const errors = {
    uname: "invalid username",
    pass: "invalid password",
  };

  //Submit handling
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //Prevent page reload
    event.preventDefault();

    var { uname, pass } = document.forms[0];

    // Find user login info
    const userData = database.find((user) => user.username === uname.value);

    // Compare user info
    if (userData) {
      if (userData.password !== pass.value) {
        // Invalid password
        setErrorMessages({ name: "pass", message: errors.pass });
      } else {
        setIsSubmitted(true);
        setLoginStatus(true);
      }
    } else {
      // Username not found
      setErrorMessages({ name: "uname", message: errors.uname });
    }
  };

  //Error messages handling
  const renderErrorMessage = (name) =>
    name === errorMessages.name && (
      <div className="error">{errorMessages.message}</div>
    );

  //Login Form
  const renderForm = (
    <div className="form">
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label for="inp" class="inp">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="inp"
              placeholder="&nbsp;"
              name="uname"
              required
            />
            <span class="label">{t("login.labelUser")}</span>
            <span class="focus-bg"></span>
          </label>

          {renderErrorMessage("uname")}
        </div>

        <div className="input-container">
          <label for="inp" class="inp">
            <input
              id="inp"
              placeholder="&nbsp;"
              type="password"
              name="pass"
              required
            />
            <span class="label">{t("login.password")}</span>
            <span class="focus-bg"></span>
          </label>

          {renderErrorMessage("pass")}
        </div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <input type="submit" value={t("login.submit")} />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="login-form">
        {Object.keys(lngs).length > 0 && (
          <div className="languageSelectLogin">
            <select
              value={lng}
              onChange={(e) => changeLanguage(e.target.value)}
              className="languageButtonLogin"
            >
              {Object.keys(lngs).map((lngKey) => (
                <option key={lngKey} value={lngKey}>
                  {lngs[lngKey].nativeName}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        )}

        <img className="pangeaLogo" src={pangeaLogo} alt="pangeaLogo" />
        <div className="title">{t("login.welcomeMessage")}</div>
        <div className="project-name">{t("login.projectName")}</div>
        <div className="login-please">{t("login.loginPlease")}</div>
        {isSubmitted ? <Navigate to="/monitoringoverview" /> : renderForm}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

i know its kind of a mess but i need to make it work soon and ill fix it up after it works, i think it might be the outlet object im redirecting to in PrivateRoutes since i console logged the value of storedLoginStatus and it seems to be true as it should and redirect to outlet which should be the current page and not the "not-logged-in" one.

any ideas? maybe i should implement session state and resolve this whole issue?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

The overt issues I see with the code:

1. You are wrapping individual routes with the `NavbarProvider` component so they each have their own independent state.
2. `loginStatus` is initially `false` in these `NavbarProvider` instances, so this is the value that will be used on the initial render when trying to access protected routes.
3. It appears you are trying to use localStorage as the source of truth for your app state when it should simply be where state is persisted to be later retrieved from, e.g. a later page load/app mounting.
4. `ProtectedRoutes` shouldn't be the component trying to set the auth state in the `NavbarProvider` component, it should only read it and act accordingly.
5. The `ProtectedRoutes` component doesn't redirect to a valid path.

## Solution

Initialize the `loginStatus` state from localStorage in `NavbarProvider`. Do the same for the index state. Use the `useMemo` hook to compute the derived `navbarData` "state" value. In fact, just about any time you see that you've coded a `useState`/`useEffect` hook coupling you should use the `useMemo` hook instead.

```
export const NavbarProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // Initialize from localStorage
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(() => {
    return !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loginStatus"));
  });
  const [selectedProjectIndex, setSelectedProjectIndex] = useState(() => {
    const storedProjectIndex = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("selectedProjectIndex")
    );

    if (storedProjectIndex !== null) {
      const parsedIndex = Number(storedProjectIndex);
      if (
        !isNaN(parsedIndex) &&
        parsedIndex >= 0 &&
        parsedIndex < NavbarData.length
      ) {
        return parsedIndex;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  });

  // Persist local state updates to localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedProjectIndex", selectedProjectIndex.toString());
  }, [selectedProjectIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("loginStatus", JSON.stringify(loginStatus));
  }, [loginStatus]);

  const navbarData = useMemo(() => {
    return NavbarData[selectedProjectIndex]?.tabs || [];
  }, [selectedProjectIndex]);

  return (
    <NavbarContext.Provider
      value={{
        navbarData,
        selectedProjectIndex,
        setSelectedProjectIndex,
        setLoginStatus,
        loginStatus,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </NavbarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Update `PrivateRoutes` to read the `loginStatus` context value and redirect accordingly. Redirect to a valid route, e.g. `"/"` for the login page.

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { loginStatus } = useContext(NavbarContext);

  return loginStatus ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Restructure the routes so there is only one rendered `NavbarProvider` and single app auth state being maintained.

```
const NavbarProviderLayout = (
  <NavbarProvider>
    <Outlet />
  </NavbarProvider>
);

const NavbarLayout = (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <PrivateRoutes />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <NavbarProviderLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <LoginScreen /> },
      { path: "*", element: <NotLogged /> },
      {
        element: <NavbarLayout />,
        children: [
          { path: "monitoringoverview", element: <MonitoringOverview /> },
          { path: "performancequality", element: <PerformanceQuality /> },
          { path: "finance", element: <Finance /> },
          { path: "simulation", element: <Simulation /> },
          { path: "userconfig", element: <UserConfig /> },
          { path: "fraud", element: <Fraud /> },
          { path: "deployment", element: <Deployment /> },
          { path: "planning", element: <Planning /> },
          { path: "settings", element: <Settings /> },
          { path: "cashflowoverview", element: <CashflowOverview /> },
          // Elections
          { path: "elections", element: <Elections /> },
          { path: "whatif", element: <Whatif /> },
          //
          { path: "overview", element: <Overview /> },
          { path: "resourcemanagement", element: <ResourceManagement /> },
          // SuperGaz
          { path: "energymonitoring", element: <EnergyMonitoring /> },
          //
          { path: "monitoring", element: <Monitoring /> },
          { path: "inquiry", element: <Inquiry /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

Comment: @NoamTheLoreFnaticHadad Welcome, glad to help and hopefully this answer addressed/resolved your question/issue. If so, then cheers and good luck! Otherwise, please feel free to ask for clarity if anything is unclear or not quite working as expected.